# kubectl apply -f error invalid type for io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.LabelSelector.matchLabels: got "map", expected "string"

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-deployment

I hope you are doing well

Please, I can't create this **Deployment**

I don't either know why or what can be the error.

It seems like some people have already had this error but I don't understand from the comment how they solve it.

I check into the Kubernetes documentation but nothing found.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: analysis-api
  labels:
    tier: msvc
    name: analysis-api
    component: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      labels:
        tier: msvc
        name: analysis-api
        component: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: msvc
        name: analysis-api
        component: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: main
        image: guitou-app/msvc-analysis-api
        env:
        - name: ENV
          value: dev
        - name: MONGODB_URI
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: env-vars
              key: MONGODB_URI
        - name: MONGODB_DBNAME
          value: guitou-analysis
```

I've got this error

```
error: error validating "infra/k8s/analysis-api.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.selector.matchLabels.labels): invalid type for io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.LabelSelector.matchLabels: got "map", expected "string"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

but I don't know what it means.
**metadata.labels**, **spec.template.labels** and **spec.selector.matchLabels** are all identical.

Where should I start to find the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be something like

```
selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: msvc
      name: analysis-api
      component: backend
```

instead

```
selector:
    matchLabels:
      labels:
        tier: msvc
        name: analysis-api
        component: backend
```